# Webpack extract-text-webpack-plugin and css-loader minification

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I am having problem minimizing the css file output by the extract-text-webpack-plugin

```js
/* webpack.config.js */
...
loader: [{test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?minimize')}]
...
plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")]
...

/* test.js */
require('./file1.css')
```

```css
/* file1.css */
@import './file2.css';
body {color: green;}
body {font-size: 1rem;}

/* file2.css */
body {border: 1px solid;}
body {background: purple;}

/* the output styles.css */
body{color:green;font-size:1rem}body{border:1px solid;background:purple}
```

In the resulting styles.css, there are 2 body tags. It seems that minifications are performed within a file (within file1.css and within file2.css) but not when the two files are combined and extracted into the final styles.css.

How can minification be performed on the final style.css? So the output is

```css
body{color:green;font-size:1rem;border:1px solid;background:purple}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could use [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin), which was created to solve this exact issue.

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin()
]
```

Comment: Will test against using `cssnano` standalone after webpack. If equivalent, I guess it will be the best answer and I will award you the bounty. Thanks for the info. Out of curiosity, the project was created 4 days ago (for reference, January 8th, 2016), how did you find it?

Comment: I googled the issue, and strangely enough this project was on the first page of Google. I must have used the right set of keywords :)

Comment: I can confirm that this as the same net result as running `cssnano` on the generated `bundle.css` file ... but directly within webpack. This is excellent news! Bounty awarded.

Comment: Should it work with sourceMap option? Because for me `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin` and `cssnano` break source maps - when I use the first one all rules point to compiled .css file instead .scss source file, when I use `cssnano` rules point to source file, but always to the end of the file.

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you so much !! :)

Answer (score 2):

For css minification you may use the webpack's CSS-loader with the "minimize" option. It solved the problem in my case:

```
webpack.config.js

...
module: {
   rules: [
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [{
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
               minimize: true
            }
         }
      },
   ]
},
...
```

Comment: This solved it for me! And perhaps an easier solution instead of installing another plugin.

Comment: As of May 2019, css-loader does not have such option. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#options

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer has stopped working with breaking change in 1.0.0 Minimize and some other options has been removed from options.

The recommended solution is to use [optimize-cssnano-plugin](https://github.com/intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin). This plugin works better with source maps than optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin.

Example:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new OptimizeCssnanoPlugin({
        sourceMap: nextSourceMap,
        cssnanoOptions: {
        preset: ['default', {
            discardComments: {
            removeAll: true,
            },
        }],
        },
    }),
]
```